# How can I see the effect of v-row using v-card?

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to make 2x2 v-card object. usign vuetify

```
<v-row>
    <v-col>
      <v-btn width="100">asfd</v-btn>
      <v-btn width="100">adsf</v-btn>
    </v-col>
    <v-col>
      <v-card width="100">adsf</v-card>
      <v-card width="100">asdf</v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

If a **v-btn** in **v-col**, it work good, but if i change **v-btn** to **v-card**, then **v-row** property is ignored. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to vue but html.

`v-btn` will resolve in a html button which has the display property set to `inline-block`, which will place the elements on the same row.
`v-card` will resolve in a html div which has the display property set to `block` which will plce the elements under each other.

For positioning element the right way look at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex

```
<div id="app" >
  <v-app class="d-flex pa2">
    <v-row justify="space-around" align-items="align-stretch">
      <v-card width="50%">adsf</v-card>
      <v-card width="50%">bcde</v-card>
    </v-row>
    <v-row justify="space-around" align-items="align-stretch">
      <v-card width="50%">adsf</v-card>
      <v-card width="50%">bcde</v-card>
    </v-row
  </v-app>
 </div>
```